# Is it possible to enable debug for specific hosts in django?

Tags: python, django, apache, debugging

I have a production server which uses Apache / FastCGI / DJango to serve up my website.

This works well and I have some cunning settings which mean that if a maintenance file exists, the world sees the maintenance message but my IP address can still work on the site. The detection of the maintenance file is done at the apache level, but is there a way I can set the DEBUG setting (normally configured through settings.py) so that debug is enabled for my IP address?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to limit Django's debug page to display only to certain IPs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649006/how-to-limit-djangos-debug-page-to-display-only-to-certain-ips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest to setup a whole extra subdomain for testing different versions of a django site.  It really is probably bad form that django doesn't plain out give examples of how to do this as it leads to people doing odd things.  My setup is nginx/ uwsgi emperor so posting config file examples prob won't help you much.